# list elements by activity

Tags: command, android-activity, clearcase, element

I'm working on automated builds and need to be able to list elements that were worked on under particular activities.  I'm new to ClearCase so I apologise for naiivety ...

My downstream build process works fine and I now need to populate a 'pre-build' area by identifying the (checked-in) files associated with one or more activities, labels etc (in fact any combination the change/release manager wants) by listing the candidate files for a build and then copying them from the M: drive (Windows).  We are using CC 7.1 with a back end on AIX and Win XP Pro desktops.  We'll use ccperl to drive the find+copy process.

I have battled with 'find' to no avail - can someone lend a hand?  All help gratefully received.

Cliff.

Comment: You can add to your question  some example of find queries you are trying, and their error messages if any: I will check them.

Answer (score 1):

- For "label" (I suppose "UCM Baselines" since you mention "activities", which exist only with UCM):

The easiest way would be to configure a config spec for a dynamic view:

```
element * MY_BASELINE
```

in order to quickly access the right files.

- For activities, you could (if there is not too much files involved), list the exact versions of each activities you want:

  cleartool descr -l activity:my_actity@\pvob

and parse the result to grep/awk only what you need.
You need only to do this within a dynamic view (any dynamic view): the activity will contain a list of *extended* pathnames, meaning you will be able to access and copy each version through that `myFile@@/main/myBranch/myVersion` path.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  Much obliged -
Cliff