# ClearCase script - I need a list of all the component of a certain stream that still needs delivery to default

Tags: shell, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I need a list of all the component of a certain stream that still needs delivery to default

Comment: Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for your questions (this one and the others)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be one simple command to use.

You would have to initiate a [*preview* of a deliver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-2-6), to see which ones would actually need said deliver.

```
    cleartool deliver -preview
```

Since the default for a deliver is to deliver all activities in the stream that have changed since the last deliver operation from the stream, that would allow for detecting any activity candidate for delivery, component after components.

You might also need to:

You would need to:

- list all components in a stream, using [fmt_ccase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-6-6):

  ```
  cleartool descr -fmt "%[mod_comps]CXp" stream:<stream>@<apvobtag>
  ```

(that would list the *modifiable* components for a given stream)

- cross-reference [the activities elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367532/6309) with the root folder of the components in order to find which component is involved by an activity listed as to be delivered.