# How to track Check-in against Incident in Clearcase UCM

Tags: clearcase-ucm, clearquest

In clearcase UCM, how I can check how many and when check-in is performed against a Incident.

Say I create the Incident(CQ 872xx) in clearquest and assigned it to the developer so that check-in can be performed in particular stream. Now at the end of release, I want to see when and how many times CQ 872xx is used for check-in in clearcase.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the ClearQuest Incident is set as an UCM activity in ClearCase (as an article like "[Setup ClearCase & ClearQuest Connectors in a ClearQuest-Enabled UCM Environment](https://jazz.net/library/article/30)" illustrates), then it is only a matter of [listing the versions stored in that activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367532/6309).

Each version checked-in against that UCM activity represents an instance when the developer has used that incident.

```
cleartool descr -l activity:CQ_872xx@\pvob
```